# To extract a word from perl using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I've this file:

```
1. heavenns 2 heavenns 3 heavenns good 4 heavenns 5heavennly bye
```

From this line, only `'heavenns'` and `'heavennly'` should be printed once.

I this code is the other question I asked in other thread. I guess as I had accepted my question there, noone will see it now, right? (I'm new here, I don't know how it works?)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = "heavenn+";
my $rx = qr/$regex/;
print "Regex: $regex\n";

my $file  = "myfilename.txt";
my %list;
my @myarr;
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Failed to open $file: $?";

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    if ($line =~ $rx)
    {
        print $line;
        $list{$line}++;
    }
 }

 push @myarr, sort keys %list;

 print "Mylist: @myarr\n"; #NOT GIVING ME UNIQUE VALUES & NOW I ONLY WANT heavenns and heavennly
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -0777 -nE'@w{m/(heavenn\w+)/g}=();say for keys %w'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the hash properly.

1. Check for existence of the word in the hash.
2. If does not exists, make an entry. If it does, skip.
3. After loop, print out the hash contents. 
   No need to use array.

Comment: Okay, I'll solve that problem. But can you tell me how to extract only words?

Comment: Refer any online documentation for Regex. m/\w/ should match words ie all alphanumberic occurances delimited by space on both sides. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out the entire line when it sounds like what you want is to just print out the words that match.  If this is the case, then the first thing you need to do is change your regex:

```
my $rx = qr/heavenn.*?\b/
```

This matches "heavenn" plus any characters up until the next word boundary.  It's hard to tell from your question if that's the exact regex you need, but it will match "heavenns" and "heavennly" so I'm sticking with that.  If this isn't what you wanted you might have to change this a little to suit your needs.

Next, just change your while loop a little bit to extract the matching words into a hash.  You can do something like this:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    $list{$_}++ for $line =~ /$rx/g;
}

say for sort keys %list;   #Need to 'use feature qw(say);'
# => prints "heavennly\heavenns\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Regex in a list contex, you get all matches. Another problem you had was the regex itself. When you use a `+` it means that the word in front of the plus will be used. You need a wildcat instead. this is the `.`. So your regex must be like `heavenn.`. For Example your problem:

```
my $regex = "heavenn.";

my $file = "myfilename.txt";
my %list;
my @myarr;

#open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Failed to open $file: $?";

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
  my @founds = $line =~ m/$regex/g;
  foreach my $found ( @founds ) {
    print $found . "\n";
    $list{$found}++;
  }
}

push @myarr, sort keys %list;

print "Mylist: @myarr\n";

__DATA__

1. heavenns 2 heavenns 3 heavenns good 4 heavenns 5heavennly bye
```

I use this way here to get all matches as an array and loop through the founds to get only 1 unique found (like you).